# Sqrt, and Math in Arrays

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty understand how to write this array. I need it to out-print 10x5 (50 elements total), and have the first 25 elements equal to the sqrt of the index that it is in, and the last 25 to equal 3 * the index. Yes, this is homework but I'm not asking for you to do it for me, I just need help! I'm getting errors when using `Math` saying that I cant use double and the double array together. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class snhu4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double alpha[][] = new double[10][5];
        double[] sum, sum2;

        for (int count=0; count<=25;count++) {
            alpha[count]= Math.sqrt(count);
        }

        for (int count=26; count<=50;count++) {
            alpha[count]= count *3;
        }

        for (int count=0; count<=50;count++) {
            System.out.print(alpha[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? How does the result differ from what you were hoping to get?

Comment: Think about where and why you are getting errors. The error contains a line number for reference.

Comment: I'm actually not getting any results. I can't figure out how to use Math with the arrays. It won't let me mix double[] with a double.

Comment: What do you mean by _mix_?

Comment: multiply/use together

Comment: To reference a 2D array, you need to reference two indices, not just one. So, for example, to access the first element, you would have to say `alpha[0][0] = Math.sqrt(count);`

Comment: Ok thank you! That is very helpful, I think I can get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `alpha` is a multidimensional array, you can't refer to its elements like a normal array.

`int myarray[][] = new int[2][2];`

In the above example, the array `myarray` is multidimensional. If I wanted to access the second element in the first array, I would access it like this:

`int myint = myarray[0][1]`;

You are trying to access a multidimensional array by using the access for a normal array. Change

`alpha[count]`

to

`alpha[0][count]`

or similar.

Read [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html) for more information on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you defined alpha as a 2D array with lets say 10 items in the first dimension and 5 in the second, and 5x10 is 50 elements.

When using your array to assign values to these elements, u must call upon the array using 2 indices, one for each dimension:

```
alpha[i][j] = /*double value*/; //with 0<=i<=9 and 0<=j<=4
```

So the first 25 elements going from left to right in dimension order is going to be:
[0to9][0] and [0to9][1] and [0to4][2]
the next 25 will be
[4to9][2] and [0to9][3] and [0to9][4]

from then on i cannot give you the answers to your homework, but the loops should look like this:

```
int j;
for(int i = 0; i<25; i++)
{
    j=i/10; //integer division will return 0 for i<10, 1 for 10<i<20, etc..
    alpha[i%10][j] = Math.sqrt(i);
}
```

and you can figure out the rest

Comment: actually 11 elements in the first dimension and 6 in the second

Comment: No, its 10 and 5. Array creation parameters takes the number of elements you want to create.  
You are welcome to use int[] array = new int[10] and array.length to check for yourself

Answer (score 0):

The 10x5 appears to be an output constraint, not a design constraint.

You are using Java, so use Java constructs, not C-language constructs;
specifically store the values in a List not an array.

Here are some hints:

1. List<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
2. for (int index = 0; index < 25; ++index)
3. Integer currentValue = Math.sqrt(index);
4. valuesList.add(currentValue);
5. for (int index = 25; index < 50; ++index)
6. Integer currentValue = index * 3;
7. valuesList.add(currentValue)
8. int count = 1;
9. for (Integer current : valuesList)
10. if ((count % 5) == 0) // write a newline.
11. System.out.print(current);
12. ++count